# Excel conditional formatting based on 2 values

Tags: excel, formatting, formula

Good Morning!

I am working on an excel spreadsheet to use as a job tracker.

I have a cell that has a date in it (which is a formula from another date cell). I need it to turn red when due, which I have managed `=AND($I$2<NOW())` 

(PS I know there are simpler ways to do this, but seeing as I need to use the AND function, I just did it this way)

However I also need it to turn back to white once the job's been finalised, which is based on a list in a subsequent column.

I have tried the following which seems to me like it should work, but it doesn't seem to work!

`=AND($I$2<NOW(),$J$2<>"Finalised")` - it works in turning the cell red when required, but when the job is finalised, the cell stays red.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a mistake with "Finalised" (Shouldn't it be "Finalized")?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me

Comment: @Faegy I'm Aussie, so finalised is right - but thank you

Comment: @CallumDA I feel exceedingly stupid. In the list that I created for the status, finalised had a space behind it and I never even THOUGHT to check, so the code was right - I'm just unobservant. Thanks for checking for me!

Comment: Glad it was just this. I'm voting to close the question as it was just a typographical error.